# How can I load vector image directly with iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

How can I load vector image directly with iPhone SDK? Just as UIImage loads bitmap images.

Comment: What format is the vector image? If it's a custom format, you can write your own parser and draw vector lines using CoreGraphics

Comment: Any standard vector format, like SVG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iPhone OS 2.1, the iPhone's WebKit supports SVG graphics natively.  You should be able to [use a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251029/svg-images-in-an-iphone-application/1251095#1251095) to load the SVG element for display.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326709/iphone-development-svg-image-in-uiwebview) provides some sample code for doing so.

Comment: Brad--I did this with PDF. (See my comment below)

Answer (score 5):

I did this recently using PDF. I saved some resolution independent images directly from Illustrator (using the smallest file size preset). I have some code (gists) [here](https://gist.github.com/1905400).

Comment: There is also a category for UIImage so that you load PDF as UIImage into any UIImageView or any view: https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF